# Why does x-vendor-feature not pass w3 validation

Tags: html, validation, w3c

Tag attributes in form of `x-feature-vendor` is now in the [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/infrastructure.html):

> For markup-level features that are intended for use with the HTML syntax, extensions should be limited to new attributes of the form "x-vendor-feature", where vendor is a short string that identifies the vendor responsible for the extension, and feature is the name of the feature.

I'm trying to [validate](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) simple code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="Name" x-vendor-feature>
  <span id="FirstName"></span>
  <span id="SurName"></span>
 </div>
</body>
```

But the validator does not allow the x-vendor-feature:

> **Error**: Attribute x-vendor-feature not allowed on element div at this point.

Have they not updated the validator? I'd like to start using `x` attributes.

Comment: "Tag attributes in form of x-feature-vendor is now in the HTML spec:" No it isn't. The document you cite is a twelve year old draft. The current HTML spec contains no such clause.

Comment: Maybe what you want is [data-* attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes)

Comment: @Alohci yes you're right answer this I'll accept